# Very simple dropbox , google drive api for PHP

Tags: php, cloud, storage, google-drive-api, dropbox

I want to store my server files on Dropbox and Google Drive with PHP. I want very very easy PHP class to save and get files between server and [DB + GD].

**In my mind:**

```
<?php

cloudPut("path/to/file.txt", "Hello World"); // Put

cloudGet("path/to/file.txt"); // Get

?>
```

Please help me. Is there any class is available for me. Please suggest me.

Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both Dropbox and Google Drive, you will need to authenticate the user.

I'd recommend doing some google searches for "dropbox php api"
I just found this one: https://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API

Or this example for Google Drive: https://gist.github.com/hubgit/2560093

Which looks like it has some great sample code to get you started with what you are looking to do.